# Data disappears when two first rows are combined as header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file I want to turn into a dataframe where I combine the two first rows into a header. The text file looks something like this:

```
            22    22     56   56    
            Q     P      Q    P
2023-10-11  1     2.5    4    6.7
2023-10-12  2     3.3    7    7.7
...
```

The resulting dataframe I want would be something like:

```
            ('22', 'Q')  ('22', 'P')  ('56', 'Q')  ('56', 'P')
2023-10-11  1            2.5          4            6.7
2023-10-12  2            3.3          7            7.7
...
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
df = pd.read_table(file_path, index_col = 0, na_values = -9999, header =[0, 1])
```

When I do this the headers are formatted as I want, but all the data (except for the dates that I use as index) disappears:

```
            ('22', 'Q')  ('22', 'P')  ('56', 'Q')  ('56', 'P')
2023-10-11  
2023-10-12  
...
```

Why does this happen and how do I avoid it?

I have tried removing the "header"-part entirely, and then the data is read as I would expect, but with only the first row as header. Using header = 1 works as well but then, of course, only the second row is used as header (and the first row with my "area numbers" disappears entirely).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
file_path = 'sample_data.txt'
df.to_csv(file_path, sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
df_read = pd.read_table(file_path, index_col=0, na_values=-9999, header=[0, 1])
print(df_read)
```